# Problem in centering table header in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, html-table

Problem in centering table header in shiny, when centering my table the first column remains aligned to the left. How do I fix this? Just below I made available my CSS code. I'm in doubt as to how to align the first column of my table. I am also in doubt, if I called the CSS correctly in my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

bd= read.csv("bd.csv", sep = ";")

ui = fluidPage(
    fixedRow(
        column(12,
               titlePanel("Tabelas"),
               sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(selectInput("TABELA", "Selecione a Tabela:", choices = bd$TABELA),
                                downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),
                   mainPanel(tags$link(
                       rel='stylesheet',
                       type='text/css',
                       href='custom.css'),
                       (tableOutput("bd"))) 
               )
        )
    )
)


server = function(input, output) {
    output$bd <- renderTable({
        bd %>%
            dplyr::filter(TABELA == input$TABELA)%>%
            dplyr::select(LOCAL, ENTREVISTAS.PRE, ENTREVISTAS.POS, CITACOES.PRE, CITACOES.POS, PERCENT.PRE, PERCENT.POS)
        }
    )
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("bd-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
        },
        
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(bd, file)
        }
    )
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


.table.shiny-table>thead>tr>th, 
.table.shiny-table>thead>tr>td, 
.table.shiny-table>tbody>tr>th, 
.table.shiny-table>tbody>tr>td, 
.table.shiny-table>tfoot>tr>th, 
.table.shiny-table>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size:80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>td, 
.table>caption+thead>tr:first-child>th, 
.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>td, 
.table>colgroup+thead>tr:first-child>th, 
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>td, 
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th {
    border-top: 0;
    font-size:80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do to format the table is to use the datatable function from the DT package.

I create a *create_dt* function with new variables to pass some values, which I use throughout the shiny application. I leave the format that I use in my tables, if you want to use it. There are many options to configure your table [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/).

```
create_dt <- function(x,y = NULL,z = NULL,w,v = NULL){
    v <- if_else(is.null(v),TRUE,FALSE)    
    y <- if_else(is.null(y),16,y)
    datatable(x,
              rownames = FALSE,
              class = "compact cell-border",
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              caption = z,
              options = list(dom = 'rtB',
                             buttons = list(list(extend='excel', 
                                                 filename = 'Nombre tabla',
                                                 text = '<i class="fas fa-download"></i>')),
                             pageLenght = y,
                             lengthMenu = list(c(y,25,50,-1),
                                               c(y,25,50,"All")),
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             initComplete = htmlwidgets::JS(
                                 "function(settings, json) {",
                                 "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});","}"),
                             columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = '_all'))
                             ),
              container = w,
              escape = v) %>% 
        formatStyle(columns = names(x),
                    color = "black",
                    fontSize = '8pt')
```

This is what my table looks like.

[example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ANYS.jpg)

And this is how I apply the function with the data:

And the Ui part:

```
fluidRow(column(6,withSpinner(dataTableOutput("resume_tbl_entero",height = '100%'))))
```

The server part:

```
output$resume_tbl_entero <- renderDataTable(
        {create_dt({React_ano_filter_general_entero() %>% 
                mutate(Resultado = str_to_sentence(Resultado)) %>% 
                pivot_wider(names_from = Resultado,values_from=Total)},
                   z = "Enterococcus")}
```

And the data used looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4IlT.jpg)

I hope it serves you greetings!